# Newtonian view on light as particles

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, history, wave-particle-duality

In an article about Eddington’s light-bending project 1919 (Historical Studies in the Physical Sciences  Vol. 11, No. 1, 1980) Earman and Glymore commented on the results which was in turn responded to by The British Royal Society.

More in passing, I assume unrelated to the Royal Society’s response, the authors commented on light bending in newtonian theory,

> “One could quite as consistently with Newtonian theory assume that gravity acts  on radiation according to some other law than that for matter, but the simplest assumption is that no action occurs or that it takes place according to the law for matter.
>
> One thus obtains a prediction of no deflection, or of the deflection given by equation (4). Eddington repeatedly claimed that these and Einstein’s second prediction were the only possibilities.”

I have seen that Newton mentioned that he favored light as particles, but the comment was possibly decoupled to his mechanics.

Is that (the article's position) still the best position on light vs newtonian theory?

Comment: By the way, in relation to "Newton mentioned that he favored light as particles", that's probably related to his [corpuscular theory of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpuscular_theory_of_light).